# How to plot a bar chart for the given scenario?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

My pandas dataframe looks like this:

[image: dataframe]

In cell no 13, I have grouped the data on basis of `Pclass` and `Survived`. It shows clearly in the output that the ratio of No of people survived to No of people not survived is greatest for `Pclass=1`, then for `Pclass=2` and least for `Pclass=3`. Now I want to show this (ratio) using a bar chart, where there is a bar for every category of `Pclass` attribute versus ratio of People survived to People not survived. But I am not able to figure out how to do so using matplotlib or seaborn.

Also how to plot a bar chart for every category of `Pclass` attribute with two values (0 and 1 for not survived and survived)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) with [`DataFrame.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html):

```
s = df.groupby(['Pclass','Survived'])['Pclass'].agg('count')

s.unstack().plot.bar()
```

Or [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
pd.crosstab(df['Pclass'], df['Survived']).plot.bar()
```

Comment: Also If we want to plot a ratio of Survived/Not Survived,we can do **s2 = df.groupby(['Embarked','Survived'])['Embarked'].agg('count'),
s3 = s2.unstack()[1]/s2.unstack()[0],
s3.plot.bar()**